# Objeto de JSON llega vacio a mi metodo

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, json

Creé la siguiente función para enviar un objeto de un servicio mediante JSON pero cuando el objeto llega tiene todas las variables vacías:

```
var cpDate = new Object();
    cpDate = {
    OllPass: '',
    NewPass: '',
    ConfPass: ''
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    // Guardar Contraseña
    $('#btnAceptarCP').click(function () {
        ChangePass();
    });
});

 function ChangePass() {
    cpDate.OllPass = $('#txtOllPass').val();
    cpDate.NewPass = $('#txtNewPass').val();
    cpDate.ConfPass = $('#txtCPass').val();
}

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '../Servicio/Servicio_Prueba.asmx/setContrasena',
    data: JSON.stringify({ solicitud: cpDate }),
    contentType: "application/json",
    async: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result.d);
    },
    error: function (result) {
        //Log the error to the console
    }
});
```

Servicio donde espero el objeto:

```
public class Servicio_Prueba : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public object setContrasena(EntidadPass solicitud)
    {
        bool guardado = true;
        solicitud.setContrasena(solicitud);
        return guardado;
    }
}
```

`EntidadPass`:

```
public class EntidadPass
{
    string OllPass { get; set; }
    string NewPass { get; set; }
    string ConfPass { get; set; }

    public void setContrasena(EntidadPass solicitud)
    {

    }
}
```

Lo que quiero saber es por qué las variables llegan vacías.

Comment: Podrías poner el diseño de la clase EntidadPass?

Comment: @FernandoForcén ya edite la pregunta donde lo puse.

Answer (score 2):

Complementando la [correcta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/54158/objeto-de-json-llega-vacio-a-mi-metodo/54236#54236) de @Said, debido a que las propiedades eran privadas y no públicas no eran contempladas en la serialización al objeto solicitud.

Otro de los problemas es a la hora de enviar el parámetro por `ajax`, considera:

```
var parametro = {
    solicitud: {
        OllPass: $('#txtOllPass').val(), 
        NewPass: $('#txtNewPass').val(),
        ConfPass: $('#txtCPass').val()
    }
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/Servicio/Servicio_Prueba.asmx/setContrasena")%>',
    data: JSON.stringify(parametro),
    contentType: "application/json",
    async: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result.d);
    },
    error: function (result) {
        //Log the error to the console
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Cambia tu clase `EntidadPass`, tus atributos no los puede serializar, porque no son públicos.

```
public class EntidadPass
{
    public string OllPass { get; set; }
    public string NewPass { get; set; }
    public string ConfPass { get; set; }

    public void setContrasena(EntidadPass solicitud)
    {
    }
}
```

ejemplo funcionando:

[Json llega vacio a webservice](http://www.lomart.mx/blog/2017/03/09/objeto-de-json-llega-vacio-a-mi-metodo-solucionado/)

Comment: Considero que la respuesta no es lugar apropiado para agregar propaganda. Por favor, quita el link.

Comment: **Es correcto tu respuesta**, es lamentable que existan votos negativos. Por mi parte te doy la Bienvenida a SOes y que sigas apoyando a la comunidad. Ten en cuenta también visitar el [Centro de Ayuda](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: @Davlio en mi caso el voto negativo fue debido a que tenía publicidad en la respuesta, esto lo podrás ver en el histórico de ediciones. Como ya se quitó el link he quitado mi voto negativo :)

Comment: @Flxtr bueno... a los que al menos ya conocemos como funciona SOes, deberíamos al menos considerar [¡Por favor, una linea clara ya de una vez como actuar en SO!](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1475/por-favor-una-linea-clara-ya-de-una-vez-como-actuar-en-so)

Comment: A todos muchas gracias, estoy tomandome el tiempo de replicar el error y subir la respuesta mi blog, para que validen que la respuesta es correcta y la causa del error. para que en un futuro a otro usuario o programador le pueda funcionar. @Davlio agradezco tu apoyo y espero poder seguir aportando.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba modificando tu Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '../Servicio/Servicio_Prueba.asmx/setContrasena',
    data: {solicitud: JSON.stringify(cpDate)}, // Esta línea es la que hay que modificar
    contentType: "application/json",
    async: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result.d);
    },
    error: function (result) {
        //Log the error to the console
    }
});
```

Explicación:

La manera en que mandas tus datos están mal:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ solicitud: cpDate })
```

estás mandando esto: `"{'solicitud': {'OllPass': '', 'NewPass': '', 'ConfPass': ''}}"`, sin embargo lo que debes mandar es algo así: `solicitud: "{'OllPass': '', 'NewPass': '', 'ConfPass': ''}"`, nota que el nombre del objeto que mandas está fuera del JSON y en tu código está dentro; lo que estás mandando es solamente una cadena sin nombre de parámetro, por lo tanto, como lo debes mandar es:

```
data: {solicitud: JSON.stringify(cpDate)}
```

Answer (score -1):

¿Puedes intentar de esta manera?

```
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = false)]
    public static object setContrasena(EntidadPass solicitud)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Cuando lo pongo como me comentas no hace el POST

Comment: Lo puse exactamente como me indicas y aun no realiza el POST si le quito el static lo envia pero sigue enviando el objeto con las variables NULL

Comment: Tienes escritas las cabeceras sobre el `Servicio_Prueba : System.Web.Services.WebService` deben estar estas cabeceras `[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]`

Comment: @GabrielJeremyRodriguezRiver a medida que el OP te vaya dando más información, podrías ir dándole más cuerpo a tu respuesta, que está muy escueta

Answer (score -2):

Me aprece que el tema es al momento de generar el json del lado de JavaScript. Intenta con `JSON.stringify(cpDate)` para que tu objeto se serialice de forma adecuada:

```js
var cpDate = {};

cpDate.OllPass = '123';
cpDate.NewPass = '456';
cpDate.ConfPass = '789';
console.log(JSON.stringify(cpDate))
```

Como verás, no es requerida la parte de `solicitud:` en la llamada `ajax`. Finalmente, tu *ajax request* quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '../Servicio/Servicio_Prueba.asmx/setContrasena',
    data: JSON.stringify(cpDate),
    contentType: "application/json",
    async: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result.d);
    },
    error: function (result) {
        //Log the error to the console
    }
});
```

Answer (score -4):

Solo define tu método como `static` y prueba

Actualización:

Como Respondio [Gabriel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/30423/gabriel-jeremy-rodriguez-river) anteriormente te deberia funcionar, si esto no funciona revisa el archivo `RouteConfig.cs` en la carpeta App_Start y modifica o comenta la siguiente linea:

```
//settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
```

Comment: Pero te refieres al método del servicio o al medoto de setContrasena?

Comment: En este sitio se esperan preguntan y respuestas de calidad. Te han faltado muchos detalles. Por favor Rokum, responde al OP editando tu respuesta y dando una explicación de por qué tu respuesta debería solucionar su problema.

Comment: Haters gonna hate: repetir código no es uno de mis estándares eso se lo dejo a profesionales redundantes y poco optimizadores, mi respuesta esta clara como el agua...